# How to use an array twice in a php script

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on a script and want to use an array called $states twice. `$states` is an array with a list of 50 states.

I am using the code snippet below to display the results.  If I only use the div with `class="table-responsive"` by itself it works and displays correctly. If I only use the div with `class="container"` by itself it also displays the results correctly.

However, when I try using both together i.e. one following the other the first one works and the second one displays nothing or at most displays the last result in the array. I have tried resetting array but nothing seems to work.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="defaultview">

    <table  class="table"  width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <? array_shift($states);
    $rows3 = array_chunk($states, 2);
    foreach ($rows3 as $states) { ?>
    <tr>
    <? foreach($states as $state){ ?>

    <td><a href="/search.php?state=<?=$state['state']?>" title="<?=$state['state']?>">
    <?=$state['state']?>
    </a></td>
    <? } ?>
      </tr>
      <? }?>
    </table>

</div><!-- /End #state -->



<div class="container" id="smallview" style="padding-left: 1px;"> 
    <ul class="list-group">

    <? 
    reset($states);
    array_shift($states);
    foreach($states as $state)
    { ?>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="/search.php?state=<?=$state['state']?>" title="<?=$state['state']?>">
     <?=$state['state']?>
     </a></li>
     <? } ?>


     </ul>
 </div><!-- /End #state -->
```

Comment: Try `unset($states);`.

Comment: you don't use the same array now do you.

Comment: @Krii sure deleting the variable will help

Comment: @Dragon what do you mean don't use the same array?

Comment: `reset()` ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php - surely the answer's not actually in the title of the question?

Comment: What about `echo $states."<br />"` instead on `echo "$states<br />"`?

Comment: @CD001 unfortunately the reset function did not work. I used "reset" in the title but it was not meant as the function. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `reset()` doesn't affect `foreach` anyway, but `array_shift()` does affect the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
array_shift($states);
$rows3 = array_chunk($states, 2);
foreach ($rows3 as $states) {
//                 ^^^^^^^
```

At this point you overwrite the original `$states` array; if the original array had an odd number of elements, say 49, at the end of the loop you would now have a `$states` array with just one element.

Further in the code:

```
reset($states);
array_shift($states);
```

After `array_shift()` the array would now be empty.

Comment: thank you so much. That is exactly what is happening. I am a newbie at all this. How would I fix this to make this work? Any suggestion would really be appreciated.

Comment: You can fix it by avoiding the same variable name as your original array, e.g. `foreach ($rows3 as $row)`.